# Excel VBA using DIR function with wildcard and values from cell

Tags: excel, wildcard, vba

I'm somewhat new to Excel VBA and am having trouble reading cell values and using them to find a file path and open the file. Here are some of the relevant facts (hopefully this is adequate specificity but please let me know if I am missing other relevant information).

- I have the first name and last name of each person in adjoining cells, e.g. first name in F4 and last name in G4.
- The files I am trying to open currently all start with "LastName, FirstName" but have different characters after them that don't follow a pattern. I'm trying to use a wildcard to make up for those unknown characters.
- All the files are stored in "Z:\Documents\Warehouse Personnel Updates\" and they are all .xlsx files.

Eventually I'm going to create a loop to open multiple files for each person listed, but currently I am just focusing on getting one open.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Sub findFile()

Dim Folder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String

FirstName = Range("F4").Value
LastName = Range("G4").Value

Folder = "Z:\Documents\Warehouse Personnel Updates\"

FileName = Dir(Folder & LastName & ", " & FirstName & "*.xlsx")

Workbooks.Open FileName
```

When I run this, I get "Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find ." Just a space and then a period to end the sentence. It seems like it isn't reading the filename at all.

If anyone has insight to what I am missing, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot open a file with a wildcard on it. Try it on windows.  You can't name any file with an *. And as a filename, it won't work as a wildcard like you want to do. Try to get all filenames in an array, and then check all items in your array and find the right one using `Instr` or something like it (maybe Mid, or Left can help too)

Comment: You should do a google search for "open workbook whose name contains a space". Also, search for "excel vba open workbook with wildcard"

Answer (score 1):

You can open a workbook using a wildcard in the Dir. This is just an example...

```
Dim sName As String
'Declare the variable for the workbook.
sName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*Smith_John*")

    If sName <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sName
    End If
```